Why isn't an in plane (IP) inverter affected during current driven SOT domain wall motion in spintronics?
I am learning about spintronics and started with the NOT gate (the inverter). The gate is represented by an in plane (IP) region in between two anti-parallel out of plane (OOP) regions, the setup lays on a heavy metal. As far as I understand (please correct me if I understand this wrong) a domain wall is moved by a applying a current trough a heavy metal which causes electrons with a certain polarized spin to be injected in the magnetic film (on top of the heavy metal). Because of spin coupling the IP region of the domain wall will try to align with the spin of the electrons but because of the Dzyaloshinskii–Moriya interaction a new IP region has to be formed to next to the previous region (to the left or the right, based on the current direction) and this causes the wall to move. In the case of an inverter we move a domain wall over an IP region but I don't understand why the inverter (which is also a IP region) wouldn't also move in the same way as the domain wall does. I feel like I am not fully grasping the way the domain walls move.
Thank you for helping !!
